# socket connected but not emit the message

Tags: javascript

Client-Side:
the socket used in website, initially connected and socket id is generated, but when try to emit the message, unable to emit from client to server-side.

```
<script>
        const socket = io("http://localhost:8080");
        socket.on("connection",() => {
        })
        const socketTrigger = () => {
        console.log("message")
        socket.emit("message", "testing data")
        }
    </script>
```

Server Side:

```
    io.on("connection", socket => {
      socket.on("message", (data) => {
        console.log("message", data)
      })
      socket.on("startBidding", isAdminPage => {
      socket.broadcast.emit("startBiddingArray", isAdminPage);
      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
          console.log("Client disconnected");
      });
      });
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You just assign a variable with an anonymous function, but you don't call it like: `socketTrigger();` at the end of the script.